# How can I decode a JSON string in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to read a string into an array in PHP, but it doesn't work for me.

The string I would like to read:

```
$output = {"message":"Approved","responseCode":"0","responseCodeDesc":"Transaction Successful"}
```

The code I am using:

```
$arr = explode(',', $output);

foreach($arr as $v) {
    $valarr = explode(':', $v);
    preg_match_all('/"(.*?)"/', $valarr[0], $matches);
    $narr[$matches[1][0]][$matches[1][1]] = $valarr[1];
}
```

Specifically, I would like to access the value for `'message'` (i.e., `'Approved'`).

I tried this, but it still fails:

```
echo 'MESSAGE ' .  $arr['message'];
```

Comment: You might want to check out [PHP's JSON functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).

Comment: What are the string's origins? It sure looks like JSON and if it is, you should be using `json_decode()`

Comment: Are you sure that `$output` is JSON object? Maybe it's just a JSON-like string.

Comment: Accidentally voted to close as duplicate, but referenced the wrong question. This is definitely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is working code,

```
  $arr = '{"message":"Approved","responseCode":"0","responseCodeDesc":"Transaction Successful"}';
  $arr = json_decode($arr, true);
  echo $arr['message'];
  print_r($arr);
```

Here is working [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/68fb6c3a4156c91d1ed7a76e4be3f85596b7fb7c)

Answer (score 0):

Thats not string, its json..

```
$array = json_decode($output,true);
```